# VB SCript - CreateObject hangs program

Tags: vbscript, freeze, createobject

**Background** : I have written a VB script to merge all word documents in a folder into one file. I run this VB script from C++ code.
When I run this VB script on server itself it works fine. However when this server code is triggered from client machine, it hangs ( this VB script still runs on server machine only).

I have removed my entire logic from VB script to find root cause and have only below code, nothing else.

```
Dim wdApp
Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.application")
wdApp.visible = false
wdApp.Quit
Set wdApp = Nothing
```

This CreateObject is causing system to hang and then gradually consuming memory and resulting into pagination.

I tried setting wdApp.visible = true -> there were no error messages.

Comment: Sounds like you need to describe the client -> server scenario a bit more how are you executing the VBScript from the client on the server?

Comment: @Lankymart It is a normal  N tier architecture.From client I call a particular operation, which triggers a parallel function on server side. Server side C++ call s this VB script. My observation is if server-client are on same machine it works fine, however if on different machines I am running into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

`CreateObject("Word.Application")` creates a new instance of Word application object

you should first try getting an already running one

this is the correct approach

```
Dim wdApp As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application") ' try getting a running instance of Word
If Err.Number <> 0 Then Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application") ' if unsuccessful, try creating a new instance of Word
On Error GoTo 0

If wdApp Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "couldn't get or create an instance of Word"
    Exit Sub
End If

wdApp.Visible = False

' your code with wdApp

wdApp.Quit
Set wdApp = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks for your response HTH, however this code also caused same result. When I trigger this server code from client, this script hangs up the system. (mentioning again, When I run this code directly on server it works fine. but when I trigger this code from client to run on server, it causes this problem

Comment: Does the client have Microsoft Word installed?

Comment: @Lankymart Yes MS office is installed on client